# Vue SSR issue with no ssr

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, vue-ssr

I'm using my own SSR boilerplate for Vue.

```
https://github.com/Djancyp/luna-vue-ssr-boilerplate
```

All working fine pages are SSR rendering.
The issue that I'm currently having is no SSR components are failing as soon as I import them to components.

server trow err:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

I'm aware of the issue is document does not exist on nodejs server.

My question is How can I stop rendering no SSR components on the server ?
-I've tried No-SSR but no joy.

my server-enty.ts

```
import createApp from './app'
const config = require('config')
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

export default context => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('what the f server')
    const s = isDev && Date.now()
    const { app, router, store } = createApp(config)

    const { url } = context
    const { fullPath } = router.resolve(url).route

    if (fullPath !== url) {
      return reject({ url: fullPath })
    }
    router.push(url)
    router.onReady(() => {
      const matchedComponents = router.getMatchedComponents()
      console.log(matchedComponents)
      if (!matchedComponents.length) {
        console.log('what the **** mate error')
        return reject({ code: 404 })
      }
      Promise.all(matchedComponents.map(({ asyncData }) => asyncData && asyncData({
        store,
        route: router.currentRoute
      }))).then(() => {
        isDev && console.log(`data pre-fetch: ${Date.now() - s}ms`)
        const meta = (app as any).$meta()
        context.meta = meta
        context.state = store.state
        resolve(app)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        return reject
      })
    }, reject)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue-SSR executes `asyncData` and `serverPrefetch` on the server-side. Remove these from your component, move the code to `created`/ 'mounted' and it should stop rendering on the server-side.

My assumption is that you are executing `document.` within `asyncData` or `serverPrefetch`.

Comment: he doesnt use nuxt i guess

Comment: Nope As I mention on top I  don't even use the imported components.

ex:
Let say I have a home page and I'm importing X component to that page.
X component has 3rth part component and this component does not support SSR.
As soon as I import 3rth part components (import QrcodeVue from 'qrcode.vue')
I'm getting document error on the server-side .I've try to wrap the root component on the home page with no-ssr but did not help.

Comment: @canonurer in such a case, you can render the third party component after the parent component is created. One way to do it is to do a conditional rendering (v-if) with the variable set on `mounted`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Promise.all(matchedComponents.map(({ asyncData }) => asyncData && asyncData({
        store,
        route: router.currentRoute
      }))).then(() => {
        isDev && console.log(`data pre-fetch: ${Date.now() - s}ms`)
        const meta = (app as any).$meta()
        context.meta = meta
        context.state = store.state
        resolve(app)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        return reject
      })
    }, reject)
```

the issue was that I was rejecting if the async template not exist.

```
Promise.all(matchedComponents.map(({ asyncData }) => asyncData && asyncData({
        store,
        route: router.currentRoute
      }))).then(() => {
        isDev && console.log(`data pre-fetch: ${Date.now() - s}ms`)
        const meta = (app as any).$meta()
        context.meta = meta
        context.state = store.state
        resolve(app)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        return reject
      })
    })
```

this resolved the issue but needs to improve the code a little bit.

Thanks for helps guys.